# Changing the color of a custom button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, css, button

Is there a way of changing a custom button color? Not a button on the visualforce page but rather the ones created under custom and links on an object.

Thanks.
-K

Answer (score 64, accepted):

## [comic but unsupported - don't do this]

This can be pulled off, but you need to get crafty :-) here's one I prepared with pink candy polka dots:

[image: pink candy polka dots]

1. go to Setup > Create > Objects > [Your Object] > Custom Buttons and Links, and hit New,
2. create a Detail Page Button whose behaviour is to Execute JavaScript,
3. modify the following JavaScript, using your lowercased button name in lieu of `your_button`:

   ```
   (function() {
     var button = document.getElementsByName('your_button')[0];
     button.style.background = 'url("https://addons.mozilla.org/_files/311357/preview_small.jpg")';
   }());
   ```
4. use a [base64 encoder](http://rot47.net/base64encoder.html) to format your JavaScript, which we'll load and execute as a [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme),
5. paste it into the formula, noting the `data:application/javascript;base64,` prefix:

   ```
   {!REQUIRESCRIPT("data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1bmN0aW9...wZyIpJzsKfSgpKTs=")}
   window.location = '/apex/ns__PageName'; //button action when clicked
   ```

The usual caveat applies: using a Data URI here may be subject to future validation, but rest assured for now [Salesforce support the use of REQUIRESCRIPT in a Custom Button](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm#REQUIRESCRIPT). Your use is only cosmetic.

Further, if you wanted to separate the button click outcome from the pink candy polka dots, you could put the cosmetic JavaScript in a separate Custom Link which you place somewhere on the page layout. It's one novel way of running JavaScript in the scope of a standard page without needing to configure the sidebar or use a narrow Home Page Component.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Black Salesforce Magician :S at roam

Comment: Would this.style.background work too without needing to fetch the HTML element ?

Comment: Woah, that is some supreme awesomeness

Comment: Well done Professor of the Dark Arts ;)

Comment: @techtrekker would've been nice to decouple the Button Name though - thanks!

Comment: Nice work herp, very, very crafty indeed :)

Comment: this is awesome!

Comment: @bigassforce put a disclaimer that says "wont work after winter 16"

Comment: @Rao: I have a solution implemented on one my clients, and suddenly it has stopped working. Your comment just caught my attention. Why it wont work after winter '16? :-|

Comment: I have got it, in this [winter 16 release note](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_requirescript.htm) .

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to declaratively modify the color of a standard button that is part of Salesforce configuration.  See this other post on some crafty ways to modify the Salesforce CSS.

[Can I apply a custom stylesheet to modify the look and feel of a standard object detail page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10469/can-i-apply-a-custom-stylesheet-to-modify-the-look-and-feel-of-a-standard-object)