# Add a button on User detail page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, page-layout, user-record

How to add my custom button on User detail page?

I've created a VF page with User standardController. I've created a button in "Edit User Custom Button or Link". This button appears in layout. But I can't place it anywhere.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Defining Custom Buttons and Links](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_custom_links.htm&language=en_US), Custom buttons aren't available on the User object or custom home pages. Depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish, you might be able to do it with a publisher action, but User doesn't appear to be supported by Global Actions either. You''l find more on them in the same area of the help section I've pointed you to.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you are right, you can't add the button to the layout. This seems to be a special behavior on user, since on other objects it works as you may have noticed. But you can use a custom link instead, which practically does the same, but only looks a bit different and is placed at the custom-links section on the layout.

If you are OK with the look, then you are done.

If the look is important, you could use some workarounds to make it look like a button tweaking this approach:
[Changing the color of a custom button](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10516/changing-the-color-of-a-custom-button/10530#10530)
use the {!REQUIRESCRIPT()} then hook in some js (setting the css of the link to fake a button)
Also you can reposition the fake-button, so that it's located on top of the layout where the buttons usually are placed. The result can look&feel 100% like a button. With jquery, it's easy.

Comment: I tried link version. It works. But I wanted a button. I'm wondering, why to allow creating a custom button if then don't allow to use it???

Comment: can't explain why. the dropzone is definitively missing in the UI. Could be a bug or a feature ;-)