# Has the lightning update modified the evaluation on anything inside bang-brackets

Tags: custom-button

I had a custom button which changed color based on a field value.
This was implemented using the solution:
[Change color of custom button based on field value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47719/change-color-of-custom-button-based-on-field-value)

This has stopped working since the upgrade to Winter '16.

Has the introduction of lightning altered the behavior of using bang-brackets?