# Displaying image on custom button in Salesforce standard page (not Visualforce page)

Tags: custom-button

[image]

Above image is the way i want to do it.Not sure if its possible in salesforce.
The circle is the image and beside that text will be displayed.
Please help !!!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be through a Javascript hack and so it's really not recommended. Anything you do come up with would be fragile in the sense that it could easily be broken by future releases.

If you do want some inspiration though, [then check out the answer on this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10516/changing-the-color-of-a-custom-button/10530#10530) about changing the colour of a button (the solution uses an image). But still, not recommended!